# Safely locking variable in Swift 3 using GCD

Tags: swift, multithreading

How to lock variable and prevent from different thread changing it at the same time, which leads to error?

I tried using

```
func lock(obj: AnyObject, blk:() -> ()) {
     objc_sync_enter(obj)
     blk()
     objc_sync_exit(obj)
}
```

but i still have multithreading issues.

Comment: You can use a serial queue or `DispatchSemaphore` for mutual exclusion of a resource. But your `lock(obj:blk:)` should also work as well. Maybe you should know that read-access also needs to be guarded.

Comment: Can you see this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640868/swift-3-gcd-lock-variable-and-block-and-release-error . There I explained with code this problem, but I am not sure how to resolve it

Comment: Already seen. As I wrote in the comment above, you need to guard read-access. Your code is using your `lock` only for mutating access.

Comment: Thank you! DispatchSemaphore solved my problem completely! If you answer question I will accept as answer.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot verify my code by any means. (That's why I cannot write anything to your older question.) Please take time to post answers by yourself and accept it. That may help many developers suffering with multithreading issues.

Answer (score 17):

### Shared Value

If you have a shared value that you want to access in a thread safe way like this

```
var list:[Int] = []
```

### DispatchQueue

You can create your own serial `DispatchQueue`.

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "SerialQueue")
```

### Dispatch Synch

Now different threads can safely access `list`, you just need to write the code into a closure dispatched to your serial queue.

```
serialQueue.sync {
   // update list <---
}
// This line will always run AFTER the closure on the previous line
```

Since the serial queue executes the closures **one at the time**, the access to `list` will be safe.

> Please note that the previous code will **block** the current thread until the closure is executed.

### Dispatch Asynch

If you don't want to block the current thread until the closure is processed by the serial queue, you can dispatch the closure asynchronously

```
serialQueue.async {
   // update list <---
}
// This line can run BEFORE the closure on the previous line
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift's concurrency support isn't there yet. It sounds like it might be developed a bit in Swift 5.  An excellent article is [Matt Gallagher's Mutexes and Closure Capture in Swift](https://www.cocoawithlove.com/blog/2016/06/02/threads-and-mutexes.html), which looks at various solutions but recommends pthread_mutex_t.  The choice of approach depends on other aspects of what you're writing - there's much to consider with threading.

Could you provide a specific simple example that's failing you?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I explained this issue in another question but I haven't got any answer until now. Here is link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45653331/safely-locking-variable-in-swift-3-using-gcd

Comment: Wrong link?  That's this question's link.

Comment: That is my question, which I posted first and after I assumed that locking is problem... But, still no solution.

Comment: "Swift's concurrency support isn't there yet. " ??? Couldn't you achieve exactly this with a dispatch queue?

Comment: Yes, Dispatch.sync is my own preferred approach, though Matt Gallagher's issues with it seem valid to me.  This isn't a native swift concurrency solution, was my point.  Swift needs something like ObjC's @synchronized, for example, to make mutex locks simpler and without performance issues of the other solutions.  Other modern languages offer such concurrency solutions.  See Swift Evolution's concurrency for swift 5 roadmap.

Comment: I noticed right now, that I have posted wrong link, here is the right one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45640868/swift-3-gcd-lock-variable-and-block-and-release-error